# Need help in using Azure managed Identity for Event grid based azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-eventgrid

I have a application sitting on Azure app service. I have an Event grid Topic which triggers an Azure Function whenver a message is sent to the topic. The messages are sent from the App service using saskey.
Currently there is no security around this whole setup.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessMessages")]
public void Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
  //code to process the message
}
```

I’m wondering if it’s possible to use managed identity in order to authenticate the Azure function.

I have been trying to explore the Managed identities related articles, but not found yet anything related to authentication via managed identities for event grid based Azure functions.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.